# How do I open a file as root in TextEdit on Lion?

Tags: macos, textedit, sudo, root

How do I open a file as root, in TextEdit? I've tried these commands as `root`, but TextEdit always say it's locked:

```
open -e /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
open -e -F /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
open -e -F -W /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

And of course `sudo !!` makes no difference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can open up a textedit instance as root by entering the full path to the actual executable :

```
sudo -b "/Applications/Textedit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit"
```

Once your root instance is open you could browse to the file you need or do this from the command line :

```
sudo su - root -c "open -e /etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! `sudo /Applications/Textedit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit` then just open the file from TextEdit

Comment: If you don't want to type that out every time you can create an alias by going to your home directory in Terminal, then `pico .bash_profile`, add `alias sudotext='sudo -b "/Applications/Textedit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit"'`, save file, restart Terminal. Now you can just type `sudotext` to start TextEdit as root.

Comment: As other answers pointed out, to do it in 1 liner the only real option is having a 3rd party editor that supports it. Then just type `open -t "/etc/hosts"` for instance. With **TextWrangler** you can simply type `edit /etc/hosts`.

Comment: What a horrible user experience! Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Why the hell have they made it so difficult for me to do things dam it!

Comment: Well, on my Yosemite 10.10.2 the `sudo -b "/Applications/Textedit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit"` doesnt work :(

Comment: Even running textedit as root, "You don't own the file and do not have permission to write to it". The mac is too smart for its own good. It detects you are not actually root, and paternalistically refuses to let you edit it.

Comment: If it does not work because you have a newer MacOS version than try: `sudo -b "/System/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit"`

Answer (score 9):

BBEdit is the free tool to do this in 2019 and it replaces all functionality of TextErangler and you can download it from the App Store and the developer web site.

---

TextEdit isn't really the right tool for editing config files -- use [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) instead.  It's free, has built-in capability to edit files with root access from an admin account, as well as things like opening invisible files and directories easily editing files over SFTP, etc.

Comment: `emacs` has a nice colour-coded conf mode, too.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in Mountain Lion.  I get an error when trying to save system config files in TextWrangler.  Has this changed?

Comment: @Simon: Sounds like you have the version of TextWrangler from the App Store, rather than the direct download from [barebones.com](http://barebones.com/products/textwrangler/download.html). If so, it's had several features (including this one) removed to comply with App Store security policies; so dump it and get the direct version instead!

Comment: What if you're on a foreign Mac without internet? The 2 hacking terminal lines accepted solution is still *generally* better. But for practical day-to-day usage, I go with 3rd parties all the way! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way to avoid running TextEdit as root:

```
EDITOR='open -Wne' sudo -e /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

You will need to quit the copy of TextEdit after editing the file.

`sudo -e`, sometimes known as `sudoedit` but not on OS X, makes a temporary copy of the file with write permission for the current user, invokes an editor on it in the usual Unix fashion, and then copies it back.

The options to `open`: `-W` waits for TextEdit to quit, so `sudo` knows when to copy the file back. `-n` ensures that it's waiting on a separate instance of TextEdit, not one you already have open which you might not want to quit. You can also substitute `-t` instead of `-e` if you have a favorite text editor other than TextEdit.

If you already have an `EDITOR` variable set to use a graphical editor with its own wait-capable command line tool (such as TextMate or BBEdit), then you don't need any of these tricks and can just use `sudo -e <file>` directly.

Answer (score 3):

Since the root user is disabled, the only way to force an arbitrary OS X app to have root permissions is to enable root and log in as root.

Apps can of course use API to ask the system for authentication and pop up the dialog you expect when asked for an administrator user and password. TextEdit doesn't have that function so you have to work around the file permissions before and after you open and write the files desired.

Have you tried using `sudo open -a textedit` to open the app?

Comment: Do you have suggestions on apps that does have that functionality? Preferably free :)

Comment: This isn't quite accurate.  In Terminal.app I run `sudo su -` to start a shell as root and then I can run `open "/Applications/Textedit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit"` successfully.  I do not have the root user enabled nor have I logged in as the root user.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo chmod +w name_of_the_file
sudo open -a TextEdit name_of_the_file
sudo chmod -w name_of_the_file
```

Should work

Comment: Okay, so it's not possible to launch TextEdit as root? I'd really like to avoid the extra hassle of changing permissions back and forth.

Comment: Things have changed in Lion, I guess it's the sandboxing

Comment: The point is that the file you are trying to open are not writable to root because of their permission. It would be the same for one of yours files (actually it is the same, except for the fact that TextEdit is "intelligent" for Users' files, so *it* changes the permission by asking you).

Comment: @Gio Indeed, it's due to Lion's sandboxing: `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` has default permissions `0444`. I've been trying all morning to edit that file (with `emacs` remotely) but never thought to check the (new Lion) permissions.

Answer (score -5):

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

works for Lion

Comment: The question is about TextEdit, not nano.