# Can I open files in TextEdit from the Terminal in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, textedit

I frequently find that a Terminal command to open a file in TextEdit would be very handy. Does such a command exist on Mac OS X?

Comment: I'm trying to open Sublime Text from command line. I did "open -a /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app my_file.txt". It works but it creates a new window every time I want to open a file. Any fix?

Comment: If you want it with `sudo`, [gota open TextEdit in root mode first](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/how-do-i-open-a-file-as-root-in-textedit-on-lion)

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi Try simply using the `sublime` command.

Answer (score 361, accepted):

`open -a TextEdit filename` should do the trick.

The `-a` flag specifies any application you want, so it's applicable to any number of situations, including ones where TextEdit isn't the default editor.

#### Other relevant options

- `-t`  opens in the default editor (i.e. if you use BBEdit, TextMate, etc.)
- `-e` will open the file specifically in TextEdit

Comment: Probably the best solution.

Comment: If you want a program whose name has spaces, you'll need to escape them, e.g., open -a Adobe\ Photoshop\ CS6 image.png

Comment: How to open it with SublimeText3 that stays in /path/SublimeText3?

Comment: In `open` command's manual, you will see `-e  Causes the file to be opened with /Applications/TextEdit`. So `open -e filename` do the same thing, and is simpler.

Comment: Are the available applications defined as those living inside of `/Applications/`?

Comment: It's all the applications registered with Launch Services, so they don't have to be in /Applications.

Comment: In `Monterey`, `open file` works for config files such as sshd_config.

Answer (score 56):

Direct, easy answer - add an alias to your ~/.bash_profile like:

```
alias textedit='open -a TextEdit'
```

Invoke it like:

```
textedit theFiletoEdit.txt
```

The difference between this and the other answer, is you can easily remember it when you want it. Typing `text` and <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete it will make it instantly available

---

For those with a bit more bash background, who want the reasoning without having to fuss with figuring it out:

- The problem is that a trivial symlink (or its ilk, like a shell script redirect) to  `/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit` causes a new instance of `TextEdit` to open the file you pass to it. This works, but does not give your expected Mac OS X default behavior.  (if you try it, you'll see)
- To get the default UI behavior, using the Mac built-in `open` command, with that '-a TextEdit' flag (that others mentioned) induces the Mac UI to have (any) currently running instance of TextEdit handle the call (with no inapropos 'sudo' needed for general case usage).

Comment: Opening a file in an already running textedit instance does not work in mojave. I tried all the flags.

Answer (score 9):

The open command can be used to open files (in their default apps, unless using the -a flag), URLs (in your default web browser), and directories (in Finder).

An example would be

```
open /Users/Example/Desktop/example.rtf
```

Comment: This is probably the easiest way to open text files for edit in a graphical editor from the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

For those finding this post:

The solution was to use the command  `sudo open -t /path/file.txt`

And the man pages for the open command also show how to do some other things like show the file in the finder.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html

Comment: Using `sudo` is unnecessary and undesirable.

Comment: Unless the file isn't accessible to the user otherwise.  But in general, agreed.

Comment: Actually, I just tried using this command with sudo to edit `/etc/hosts` on Lion and it just doesn't work (as expected). It doesn't allow me to **edit** the file. Only clone it. Might as well go without the `sudo`, in this case. The file will be marked as *locked* anyway. To really be able to do so, have to first open the TextEdit in root mode, or just use a different editor: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/how-do-i-open-a-file-as-root-in-textedit-on-lion

Answer (score 2):

This is not a programming question. But I did a quick google and found this site:

http://ss64.com/osx/

http://ss64.com/osx/pico.html pico: Simple text editor

http://ss64.com/vi.html vi: Text Editor

And this site explains how to use TextEdit from terminal.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2754/os_x_edit_file_using_textedit_as_root_superuser/

Comment: None of those links demonstrate how to open the file in textEdit.

Comment: The last link does.

Comment: It absolutely does, thanks for adding that, you are a much faster googler than I.

Comment: Does that work? Cause I have no experience with Mac OSX (Windows fan boy ^^)