# How to create a text file and a folder from terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

How, from a Terminal, do I make a plain text file and a folder?

Comment: What kind of file? An empty file? A text file? An image? There's not enough information here to really give you a succinct answer. If you can clarify, I'll reopen the question.

Comment: I suppose `touch file` is far too brief to serve as an answer...

Comment: @bmike I'd say yes it's to short, since it could be argued that the primary function of `touch` is to "change file access and modification times" (from `man touch`), unless you mention that `touch filename` only creates _filename_ if it doesn't already exist.  Otherwise it does its primary function.

Comment: @IanC sorry, a txt fire and a folder.

Comment: For the record this is standard Unix, so Linux/Unix tutorials are helpful in general. Only major difference is that MacOS filesystems by default are case insensitive.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A directory can be made using the [mkdir](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mkdir.1.html) command. To make a child directory of the current directory it's simply:

```
mkdir somechild
```

This will create a directory (shown as a folder in Finder) named `somechild`.

A text file can be created in a few different ways. The simplest being the [echo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/echo.1.html)'ing of text and redirecting it in to a file like so:

```
echo This is some text > myfile.txt
```

This will create `myfile.txt` and its contents will be the string `This is some text`.

You can also use a command line text editor such as [vim](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/vim.1.html) or [emacs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/emacs.1.html) or [nano](https://web.archive.org/web/20200625054727/https://opensource.apple.com/source/nano/nano-5/nano/doc/texinfo/nano.html) to start a new text file. The following start a new text file and open them in the editor for each of the aforementioned editors:

```
vim myfile.txt
emacs myfiles.txt
nano myfile.txt
```

The [nano](https://web.archive.org/web/20200625054727/https://opensource.apple.com/source/nano/nano-5/nano/doc/texinfo/nano.html) text editor is probably the most new-user-friendly of those three choices.

Comment: Just in case someone wonders: [Can I open files in TextEdit from the Terminal in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/25844/21950)

Comment: @ankii Why the redirect to archive.org? Also, it seems that the edit you approved only fixed some of the broken links :-)

Comment: @nohillside The link will break again..

Comment: @ankii Well, there are a lot of links on this site... :-)

Answer (score 28):

To create an empty text file, just use:

```
touch file_name.txt
```

From `man touch`: The touch utility sets the modification and access times of a file. If the file does not exist, it is created with default permissions.

Comment: Technically, `touch` creates an empty file if the file does not exist, not a text file.