# View hidden folders on MacOS Mojave? cmd+shift+. does not work

Tags: macos, finder, invisible-files

Since I'm not really great with using the terminal, I would like to see hidden folders on my Mac through the regular user interface. However, I cannot show my hidden folders. I tried things I found on the internet but they did not work for me. I tried

1. cmd+shift+dot - nothing happens
2. settings > Keyboard > turning on and off "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"
3. settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Restore Defaults
4. terminal.app > `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles ["yes"/"YES"/" "]` [source](https://www.minitool.com/news/show-hidden-files-mac.html)
5. at the folder I want to view the hidden contents of, I pressed Alt while clicking Go. after the "Library" folder showed up in "Go," I clicked it and saw many folders in Library, but still didn't see any folders with . in front. [source](https://www.minitool.com/news/show-hidden-files-mac.html)

My main goal is to copy and paste into a .gitignore file that is stored in a specific folder on my desktop. I am having troubles doing it through the terminal so I thought this would be easier but it is apparently not. :)

**Question:** How can I fix this issue and allow myself to see hidden folders on my Mac?

I don't have a strong background in this stuff and am not trained in computer science/tech stuff.

I have macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of hidden items (files or folders) on macOS:

- Those which start with `.` whose hidden bit it set by default.
- Those with no starting `.`, but `chflags` set to hidden. Run `man chflags` to see more info.

> I clicked it and saw many folders in Library, but still didn't see any folders with . in front

Those folders are of the second type.

> However, I cannot show my hidden folders.

Let's see if there's a problem with hidden files itself. In Terminal, run :

```
cd ~/Downloads
mkdir test_hidden && cd test_hidden
touch empty
touch .empty_h
open .
```

In this folder that opens, do you see files (dis)appearing if you toggle `command+shift+.` ?

Update: Restarting and running `killall Finder` helped.

For the `.gitignore` file, use `ls -a` command to list all items in a directory. If there is a `.gitignore` file there, you can run

```
open .gitgignore
```

to open it with default text editor. Or `nano .gitignore`. Or specify a text editor:

- [Can I open files in TextEdit from the Terminal in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25844/can-i-open-files-in-textedit-from-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: Cmd+shift+. didn't work but one odd thing that happened is the ```empty``` file I created ended up outside of ```test_hidden``` even though I ran mkdir first. Is it supposed to do that?

Comment: This is helpful, a workaround for this that worked for me is ```open -a TextEdit .gitignore```. Thank you. But I wonder why my Mac will not show hidden files.. very strange

Comment: @EvC oops.. I didn't mention a cd command. edited the answer.

Comment: Do you see any improvement after running `killall Finder`  ? this relaunches Finder. Or a restart?

Comment: somehow this fixed it! Yes! I can now view my hidden files! They do not toggle when I try cmd+shift+. but this works for some reason! Thank you!