# Why can't I change a restricted System file after doing csrutil disable?

Tags: macos

I want to change a file in `/System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/Resources/`, but even after disabling `csrutil` in recovery mode, I still get this flags with `-ls -lO <filename>`:

> -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  restricted, compressed 6365 23 Aug 03:55 Keyboard-de.plist

UPDATE: I just figured out that I can change the ownership, so I should be able to `cp` and `rm` the file I want to change.
Still, when I am opening the file with TextEdit, I can't do anything, but I think this should be possible too.

EDIT: To check if SIP is still on, type `csrutil status` in the terminal. With SIP on it's impossible to change those files as any user.

`sudo nano` worked just fine. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Did you try to edit the file with `sudo`?

Comment: When I am doing this `sudo open Keyboard-de.plist ` I can't change anything.

Comment: Try `sudo nano Keyboard-de.plist`

Comment: And `sudo touch /usr/bin/crazy-name-which-doesnt-exist`. If this fails, SIP is still active

Comment: It didn't fail! Thanks :D I just touched something crazy!

I believe I should enable this SIP again, righty?

Comment: Delete the crazy file first, then enable SIP, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restricted flag only applies with System Integrity Protection enabled. It tells SIP which files to protect. If you disable SIP, the restricted flag has no effect.

Disabling SIP doesn't give *you* permission to the files though. You'll still need sudo or change the permissions yourself to edit the files.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Still I haven't got, why nano is 'stronger' than textedit.

Comment: @Dennis TextEdit, like other GUI apps, run as the current user. `sudo open …` runs open as sudo, not TextEdit. [If you want to open TextEdit as root, you need to run the binary as root.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/how-do-i-open-a-file-as-root-in-textedit-on-lion) Alternatively, use a different GUI editor which handles edits to files like this—I recommend TextMate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This resolved the issue completely now.